# Copy values only from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with an active filter and I would essentially like to delete anything but the filtered data since there are thousands of other irrelevant rows behind the filter.

As a solution, I was planning on copy-pasting the range of value of the filtered data to a clean sheet:

```
function formatUserSheet_(id, sheet) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheetToCopyFrom = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var sheetToCopyTo = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheetToCopyFrom.getRange("AT:BH").copyTo(sheetToCopyTo.getRange(1,1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
}
```

Unfortunately the result is almost perfect except returns #REF! errors because it is carrying over formulas, not just values.

Comment: well if you want to set values in a `Range`, you need to use the `Range#setValues()` method. Of course the method that copies a Range will copy it, and will not make formulas values (or values formulas).

Comment: Copying a range with setValues() does not work with filtered rows. Why would copying a range with SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES not work?

Comment: When I select a range in Google Sheets, copy, and then select "Paste Special" and choose "Values Only" this works. I can't mimic this behavior with Apps Script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want to use is [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed) with 3 arguments. If you only put 2 arguments, it's using [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options), so the paste type is the default one.

If you add false at the end of the function for the parameter `transposed`, it will copy the values correctly.

```
sheetToCopyFrom.getRange("AT:BH").copyTo(sheetToCopyTo.getRange(1,1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

For some reason the example only use 2 parameters, I guess it must have changed and they didn't update the example...